# teechart html5 stacking 2 bars including negative values

Tags: teechart

I'm using the HTML5 Teechart components from Steema.
I cannot figure out how to get 2 series for the same x-value stacked on each other, where one serie contains negatives.
For instance, for the same x values, if serie 1 has value 5, and serie 2 has value -5, they are 'stacked' upon each other...
What I would like is see serie 1, from 0..5, and serie 2 from 0..-5

```
Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Bar([5,3,2,7,1]) );
Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Bar([-5,-3,-2,-7,-1]) );
Chart1.series.items[0].stacked=true;
Chart1.series.items[1].stacked=true;
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks,
bram

Answer (score 0):

What about setting stacked to false? It would be similar to negative values as in [this example](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/series/bar/barnegative.htm). Full TeeChart for HTML5 demo [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Narcis.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not what I'm looking for. I would like the 2 series to share the same X-value. Not shown next to each other (as in the example). My purpose is to show Electricity production and consumption per day. So x-axis is datetime, and Y has on the positive site electricity produced. and negatively is consumed.

Comment: @Bram ok. In that case it's not possible for now I'm afraid. I added your request to the wish-list (TF77016654) to be considered for inclusion in future releases.